# Working SQL query fails in Hibernate @Formula

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have a SQL query that I have tested both on my SQL server directly, and via a native query in a repository using Hibernate/JPA. I also have a model whose attribute needs to be set using a query, but Hibernate seems to incorrectly turn the @Formula annotation into SQL when I see the generated SQL via a trace. I have tried several variations of this specific bit of SQL, but all of them fail being incorrectly converted to SQL somehow. Pagination also will break some of the variant queries I attempted, even if the query for page 0 works.

Here is the code that fails:

```
@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATEADD(\"ss\", -DATEPART(\"ss\", b_e.currentTime), b_e.currentTime)) FROM braking_enforcement as b_e WHERE b_e.trainSymbol = trainSymbol)")
private Integer dupBrakingEvent;
```

trainSymbol is another property inside the model.

In this specific query, a trace on the SQL Server shows the following as part of the overall query generated by Hibernate:

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TOP(@P0) DATEADD("ss", -DATEPART("ss", b_e.currentTime), b_e.currentTime)) FROM braking_enforcement as b_e WHERE b_e.trainSymbol = train0_.trainSymbol) as formula179_
```

The TOP(@P0) is incorrect SQL syntax and causes the query to fail. Is there any workaround to this problem that will allow me to still use a model attribute (rather than having to do additional queries after retrieving the model initially)?

Comment: Remove the quotes around `ss`. Does it still fail?

Comment: @WolfgangK I actually had to add those or Hibernate would interperet ss as a column and try to append train0_ to it in the generated query and it would fail due to bad syntax. SQL thankfully allows for that argument to be surrounded by double quotes.